# Codeigniter: Select based inquiries

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter, mysqli

I am having a strange issue with codeigniter where no SELECT based inquiries seem to be going through to my sql database.
Originally I had something like:

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function foo(){
         $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM 'table_name'");
         }
```

and this returned an empty result array when inspected with print_r.
So then I switched to:

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function foo(){
         $query = $this->db->get('tracker');
         print_r($this->db->last_query());
         print_r($query);
         }
```

$this->db->last_query showed me that even though a correctly formatted statement, SELECT * FROM 'table_name', was being attempted, nothing was showing up in the results array. Troubleshooting has shown me that:

1.insert statements like "$this->db->query("INSERT INTO table VALUES"...) still work fine.

2. The SQL queries being sent with get() still work on the SQL tab of phpmyadmin
3. The sql statements appear to be getting through to the database because I am returned a mysqli conn_id.
4. Changing browsers and/or restarting mamp doesnt work.

If anyone has had this issue before or sees something obvious that I'm missing I would be very grateful to know.

Thank you in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove using the table name in single quotes.

```
public function foo()
{
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
     $result = $query->result_array();
     print_r($result);
}
```

And also in order to see the compiled query use:

```
echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

To display the result, you need to get `->result()`. For example:

```
$obj_table = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM 'table_name'");
print_r($obj_table->result());
```

You may refer this documentation for further information:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Hopes answered your question.

Comment: THat does answer the question perfectly thank you so much! I had always thought print_r() would work as universally in CI as it does elsewhere in php but I guess not!

Answer (score 1):

For your both method you need to get the `record set` like below

**Method 1 :** use `result_array` to get the result as array .

```
    public function foo(){
         $q= $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM 'table_name'");
         $result= $q->result_array();
         print_r($result);
    }
```

**Note :** you can also use this  `$result= $q->result();` you will get record set as objects.

**Method 2 :**

```
      public function foo(){
         $query = $this->db->get('tracker');
         $result = $query->result_array();

         print_r($result );
         //print_r($this->db->last_query());

      }
```

Comment: Thank you for the very well explained answer. I guess it was the $q->result that was the missing link for me!